# Nginx Gunicorn Django -- upstream prematurely closed connection Error

Tags: django, asynchronous, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I am pretty new to NGINX, GUNICORN, DJANGO setup. I am using supervisor between nginx, gunicorn. Without NGINX, setup works well with supervisor and gunicorn and I can see the result through my server IP. But when i am using nginx to serve the requests, the error "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" occurs. please anyone help me in this?

```
Supervisor command I am using:
sudo /path/to/gunicorn/gunicorn -k gevent --workers 4  --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock --chdir /path/to/application wsgi:application --timeout 120
```

below is the nginx.conf i am currently using and it is working as expected. but i am not sure it is up to the mark. Please look into this. Thanks.

==============Update=============

```
upstream xxxx {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
}

server{

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name xxx.in www.xxx.in;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

    server{
         listen 443 ssl;
         ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.in/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.in/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
            location /static/ {
                root path/to/project;
        }

        location / {
            include         uwsgi_params;
            proxy_pass      http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this steps:

- First of all be sure that gunicorn is creating `.sock` file running with supervisor. You can ensure it with

  ```
  $sudo supervisorctl status <name-of-supervisor-task-for-it>
  (check if service is RUNNING)

  $ls /tmp    
  (There should be a gunicorn.sock file existing there)
  ```
- Also be aware of user that you are assigning to supervisor config. In this case you don't need to set root before command, just give privilege of root user to config file. like this:

  ```
  [program:myprogram]
  command=/path/to/gunicorn/gunicorn -k gevent --workers 4 --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock --chdir /path/to/application wsgi:application --timeout 120
  <other commands>
  user=root
  ```
- And you nginx config should should look like this:

  ```
  upstream django {
  server unix://tmp/gunicorn.sock;
  }


  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name <your_app_domain_here>;
  location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  proxy_pass http://django/;

  }
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I  am sure that .sock file is getting created in /tmp folder. I will do the other changes and reply back.

Comment: Hi, I am really confused in giving the proxy_pass address. How to give the address and what is the process going behind?

Comment: which part you are confused. update your post and add your nginx config. I will correct it for you.

Comment: Hi  Reza Torkaman Ahmadi, I am able to do it now. I gave my .sock path to proxy_pass . and it is working. is it the correct way of doing? I updated workign nginx.conf file

Comment: For future reference, the directive `proxy_pass http://django/;` refers to the `upstream django` block defined earlier in the configuration. If you change the name of the upstream, you should change the URL too.